# Java .charAt(i) comparison issue

Tags: java, string, comparison, char

Why when comparing a char against another it must be taken also from a string? For example;

*This does not work*

```
   while(i < t.length() && zeroCount < 5) {
        if(t.charAt(i) == 0){
            zeroCount++;
        }
        i++;
    }
```

*Nor does this*

```
char zero = 0;

      while(i < t.length() && zeroCount < 5) {
            if(t.charAt(i) == zero){
                zeroCount++;
            }
            i++;
        }
```

The only way I managed to get it working is like this...

```
String zeros = "0000000000";

      while(i < t.length() && zeroCount < 5) {
            if(t.charAt(i) == zeros.charAt(i)){
                zeroCount++;
            }
            i++;
        }
```

Can anyone explain if am doing something wrong, or if it is just not acceptable to do it like the top 2 examples. If so, why?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You're confusing

```
char zero = 0;
```

with

```
char zero = '0';
```

The former is the null-character (ASCII value of zero), whereas the latter is the character representing the digit zero.

This confusion is a rather unfortunate hang-over from C, with `char` variables being treated as numbers as well as characters.

Answer (score 4):

You are looking for the character '0'? Then compare to '0', not 0.

Answer (score 4):

You're comparing against Unicode value 0 (aka U+0000, the "null" character) - which is not the same as the Unicode character *representing the digit 0*.

Use '0' instead of 0:

```
while(i < t.length() && zeroCount < 5) {
    if(t.charAt(i) == '0'){
        zeroCount++;
    }
    i++;
}
```

Comment: I’m not comfortable with telling people to use `charAt`: it’s broken by design.

Answer (score 3):

Use '0' instead of 0.

Answer (score 3):

The simple answer is that the value `0` is not the same as the character `'0'` which has an ASCII code of `48` (IIRC).

You should compare it with the char value `charAt(i) == '0'` or subtract the char before comparison `charAt(i) - '0' == 0`

Comment: I don’t think you should tell people to use the old broken `charAt` method.  Too many problems.

Answer (score 3):

These other answers have it right, but there’s one very important thing you should know. You should never use `chatAt`!  You should only use `codePointAt`.

Similarly, you mustn’t blindly use `i++` to bump through a string.  You need to see whether `s.codePointAt(i) > Character.MAX_VALUE` to know whether to give an extra `i++` kicker.

For example, to print out all the codepoints in a `String s` in standard "U+" notation:

```
private static void say_U_contents(String s) { 
    System.out.print("U+");
    for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
        System.out.printf("%X", s.codePointAt(i));
        if (s.codePointAt(i) > Character.MAX_VALUE) { i++; }  // UG!
        if (i+1 < s.length()) { System.out.printf("."); }
    }
}
```

That way you can output like `U+61.DF`, `U+3C3`, and `U+1F4A9.1F4A9` for the corresponding strings.  That last one looks like `"\uD83D\uDCA9\uD83D\uDCA9"`, which is simply insane.

Comment: Your answer is confusing for someone who doesn't know about charsets. For finding `0` (or any BMP character) there is nothing wrong with `charAt`, or what problems do you mean?

Comment: @Ishtar: The problems I have are that character counts will be off.  Something like `"\uD83D\uDCA9\uD83D\uDCA9\u0000\uD83D\uDCA9\uD83D\uDCA9"` has only 5 code points in it, with the NUL at number 3.  That’s why the Java Pattern `^.....$` matches it: because the Pattern class always deals in logical units, as is proper.